# How to give Choice of Numbers to Call using Intent.ACTION_CALL?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to give the option of two numbers on a click of a button to make a call on the number directly but when I am selecting one of the numbers it is going to the dialer screen but "Ljava.lang.CharSequence" is written there and a dialog box with a message service is not supported pops up.

Here is my code:-

```
phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                final CharSequence numbers[] = new CharSequence[] {"02212345678","+14356789809"};

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder.setTitle("Select number to call");
                builder.setItems(numbers, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        String call = "tel:" +numbers;
                        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(call));
                        startActivity(callIntent);


                    }
                });
                builder.show();


            }
        });
```

Comment: have added call permission in manifest file..

Comment: @Dilip yes i have already gave permission "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>"
the problem is with the array i guess as if i am passing a single number it is working fine.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. If you want to give a choice, you should give a choice. You are just using parameter of a wrong type.

Comment: and you are passing whole array calling string that is wrong...

Comment: @M.Prokhorov sir can you please explain how can i do it ... as in my code i am giving choice using dialog box.

Comment: @Dilip can you please guide me how to do it correctly.

Comment: @HimanshuAgnihotri, Ok, I see now that you display some choice on UI, but you then ignore the user choice and send whole array anyway.

Comment: I think you can use Bottomsheet  or custom Dialog List to select one number from list.

Comment: On click of a phone number from dialog, you're getting a *position* in `onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)` callback. use the position like this:   `String call = "tel:" +numbers[which];`

Comment: @whenthemorningcomes thank you yeah i forgot to put that [which]. Thanks Mate.

Comment: @HimanshuAgnihotri welcome

Comment: Please Upvote the question guys if you feel this can help other members too. I have edited the title for ease of finding solution for this sort of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 String call = "tel:" +numbers;
```

To

```
String call = "tel:" +numbers[which];
```

Comment: Please Upvote the question if you feel this can help other members too. I have edited the title for ease of finding solution for this sort of question.

Comment: @HimanshuAgnihotri sure! same you will also up vote answer too

Answer (score 0):

```
phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             String number = "02212345678";

                          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder.setTitle("Select number to call");
                builder.setItems(number , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        String call = "tel:" +number ;
                        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(call));
                        startActivity(callIntent);


                    }
                });
                builder.show();


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete code for giving choice of numbers and calling the selected number on a Button Click. I hope this will help other members too.

```
phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                final CharSequence numbers[] = new CharSequence[] {"+1xxxxxxxxx","+1xxxxxxxxxx"};

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder.setTitle("Select number to call");
                builder.setItems(numbers, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        String call = "tel:" +numbers[which];
                        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(call));
                        startActivity(callIntent);

                        // the user clicked on colors[which]
                    }
                });
                builder.show();


            }
        });
```